# Перекрестный запрос

Tags: sql, postgresql

Задание: Написать перекрестный запрос
В качестве столбцов взять значения квартала поля ДатаОплаты,
в качестве строк – значения поля НомерТелефона.
На пересечении строк и столбцов отобразить соответствующие итоговые суммы оплаты, т.е.
значения функции Sum от поля СуммаОплаты.
Условие отбора: номера телефонов, начинающиеся на 476

Проблема: в данный момент кол-во столбцов т.е года выплаты, заданы статически, а нужно чтобы динамически все года учитывал

```
SELECT phone_number,
    SUM (CASE date_part('year', payment_date) WHEN '2021' THEN payment_sum ELSE 0 END) AS "2021",
    SUM (CASE date_part('year', payment_date) WHEN '2022' THEN payment_sum ELSE 0 END) AS "2022",
    SUM (CASE date_part('year', payment_date) WHEN '2023' THEN payment_sum ELSE 0 END) AS "2023"
FROM payment
where cast(phone_number as varchar(50)) like '476'
GROUP BY phone_number
```

Такая бд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Табличные функции](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/tablefunc) --> crosstab()